# Replace multiple spaces by a single space if they don't appear between quotes?

Tags: python, regex

I have a use case where I want to replace multiple spaces with a single space unless they appear within quotes.  For example

Original

```
this is the first    a   b   c
this is the second    "a      b      c"
```

After

```
this is the first a b c
this is the second "a      b      c"
```

I believe a regular expression should be able to do the trick but I don't have much experience with them.  Here's some of the code I already have

```
import re

str = 'this is the second    "a      b      c"'
# Replace all multiple spaces with single space
print re.sub('\s\s+', '\s', str)

# Doesn't work, but something like this
print re.sub('[\"]^.*\s\s+.*[\"]^, '\s', str)
```

I understand why my second one above doesn't work, so would just like some alternative approaches.  If possible, could you explain the parts of your regex solution. Thanks

Comment: Will you have something like this: `asdasdasd"asdasdasd____asdajskd"` (`_` stands for spaces). Do you work with only space, or do you also want to deal with new line also?

Comment: Yes. Inside quotes can be anything and it should be ignored

Comment: `Inside quotes can be anything` Can it contain new line?

Comment: No. Anything that can be matched by '.+'

Comment: Can it contain escaped quote? What is your expected output for this input `"dd____ggg"__sdf"`?

Comment: I suspect "dd____ggg"__sdf", since that is inside full quotes.  Sorry I can't be more specific, but the document I'm working from simply says "do not remove extra spaces from any values that are inside quotation marks"

Comment: You should be very clear about the requirement, since you can get vastly different result with different requirement.

Comment: I am going to proceed assuming that it is the outer most quotes that count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no `"` within the `"substring"`

```
import re
str = 'a    b    c  "d   e   f"'  
str = re.sub(r'("[^"]*")|[ \t]+', lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else ' ', str)

print(str)
#'a b c "d   e   f"'
```

The regex `("[^"]*")|[ \t]+` will match either a quoted substring or one or more single spaces or tabs. Because the regex matches the quoted substring first, the whitespace inside it will not be able to be matched by the alternative subpattern `[ \t]+`, and therefore will be ignored.

The pattern that matches the quoted substring is enclosed in `()` so the callback can check if it was matched. If it was, `m.group(1)` will be truthy and it's value is simply returned. If not, it is whitespace that has been matched so a single space is returned as the replacement value.

Without the lamda

```
def repl(match):
    quoted = match.group(1)
    return quoted if quoted else ' '

str = re.sub(r'("[^"]*")|[ \t]+', repl, str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that will work reliably every time, no matter the input or other caveats like not allowing embedded quotes, then you want to write a simple parser not use RegExp or splitting on quotes.

```
def parse(s):
    last = ''
    result = ''
    toggle = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == '"' and last != '\\':
            toggle ^= 1
        if c == ' ' and toggle == 0 and last == ' ':
            continue
        result += c
        last = c
    return result

test = r'"  <  >"test   1   2   3 "a \"<   >\"  b  c"'
print test
print parse(test)
```